# Sending a Async HTTP post request on iOS even if app is terminated

Tags: ios

I work on an app that uses HTTP post requests to send diagnostic data to a remote server as our app runs. Currently we queue the message up to be sent by another thread in our app (using our own platform agnostic code to queue and `curl` to send).

The issue I'm trying to solve is that if the app crashes (or is terminated in any other way - though crashes are my main concern) between when the diagnostic post is queued and when it is actually sent on the other thread the information will never actually be sent. It should be noted that we are already using crashlytics for crash reporting. This diagnostic info is on top of that (largely info about the state of the app, detected recoverable errors, etc).

I've had a couple ideas on methods to handle this:

1 - On other platforms I might launch a new process that handles sending these requests, but what information I've found it looks like you are not allowed to do this on iOS.

2 - I could also queue up these requests on disk so we can send them the next time our app launches if we fail to send them immediately. However, this requires waiting until when (and importantly if) the user boots our app again (part of what we use this diagnostic info for is debugging issues new users have - if a crash occurs for a new user it's very possible they won't open it again).

​*Does iOS offer any mechanism that would make this possible?*​

Right now we're using `curl` to send these requests, but I could switch to an iOS specific API if it provides this. I've found `NSURLConnection::sendAsynchronousRequest` but it seems like this still all happens within my application (meaning I'd have the same issue).

Comment: If your app is terminated then generally it is terminated until the user launches it again. There are specific background cases such, as VoIP push, that can relaunch a terminated app.  Your best bet is option 2 and send the data when the user relaunches your app.  Chances are if the app crashes then the user may re-launch straight away as they are trying to do something in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is "Not Running", meaning that it was killed by the user or was never started, you cannot do anything in the background as a developer at all.

If your app is in the "Suspended" or "Background" states, you can request background scheduling time and may be able to send then.  I am not positive, but I think that a crash doesn't remove you from these states.

Your background function is executed in the AppDelegate.

To support this:

1. Check the box Background fetch in the Background Modes of your app’s Capabilities.
2. Use `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(_:)` to set a time interval appropriate for your app.
3. Implement `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)` in your app delegate to handle the background fetch.

This will allow you to fire in the background if at all possible.

Sample code since this is Stack Overflow:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print ("Backgrounding happened")
    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

Bear in mind that the fetch interval is what you want, not what you will necessarily get.

Comment: `I am not positive, but I think that a crash doesn't remove you from these states.` If this is the case - are you saying `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)`  may be able to execute even if my app has crashed? I had assumed a crash would be the same as killing - the app (and all code it ran) would no longer exist at all.

Comment: There's an article on reliable crash reporting here that might be interesting:  http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html  It's old but the premises apply.